# display:none; displays 'none' in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

[This jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AE2X3/) works in Google Chrome, but in Internet Explorer then when the close icon is clicked the browser removes the pop-up element but results in the text 'none' being displayed in the browser window. Please explain how I can resolve this issue.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="popup">
    <!-- Close popup link -->
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none';">X</a>
</div>
```

Comment: does it happen in both browsers you mention?

Comment: Same thing happening on Firefox 4.0

Comment: In Google Chrome it works great and removes the element without displying the text 'none' in the browser. In IE however it displays the text 'none' in the browser window as well as removing the element.

Comment: Strange issue, that's for sure. I'd love to see the explanation.

Comment: you should put the code on your question in case the link dies. One should never assume that the links will last forever

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use onclick for the event handler instead of href http://jsfiddle.net/AE2X3/4/

```
<div id="popup">
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('popup').style.display='none';return false;" id="close_popup"></a>
        <p>This is a pop-up.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I am accepting your answer. I now realize that JavaScript belongs in JavaScript events, and the href attribute is for URLs thank you!

Answer (score 9):

I think what's happening is that the assignment is returning its result, and the browser is then displaying that. If you add `void(0)` to the end of your JavaScript, it won't be displayed.

Let me add that [amit_g's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598110/displaynone-displays-none-in-browser/5598162#5598162) is more correct than mine. He correctly points out that this sort of behaviour belongs in the `OnClick` handler, not in the `href` attribute.

Comment: +1 Now I get it :). That's why I love this job, you learn something new every day.

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
<div id="popup">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';" id="close_popup"></a>
        <p>This is a pop-up.</p>
</div>
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/NFyD5/)***