# Hiding a sub-navigation UL on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a site with a secondary navigation that drops down when the user mouses over a primary navigation heading. I'd like for these drop-downs to behave more like a "normal" drop-down, whereby it disappears upon being clicked.

Usually, this wouldn't be an issue, but because this site relies on anchored links for the secondary navigation, the drop-down lingers after being utilized. It's not hugely annoying *per se*, but I'd prefer it to behave more like people generally expect drop-downs to behave.

Unfortunately, my abilities with jQuery/javascript are inadequate, and I'm coming up short.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the Javacript:

```
function closeList1() {
    var list = document.getElementById("list1");
    if (list.style.display == "block"){
        list.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function closeList2() {
    var list = document.getElementById("list2");
    if (list.style.display == "block"){
        list.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

the HTML...

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#first" onClick="closeList1">FIRST</a>
        <ul class="first" onClick="closeList1" id="list1">
            <li><a href="#firstone">ONE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#firsttwo">TWO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#firstthree">THREE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#firstfour">FOUR</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#second" onClick="closeList2">SECOND</a>
        <ul class="second" onClick="closeList2" id="list2">
            <li><a href="#secondone">ONE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#secondtwo">TWO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#secondthree">THREE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#secondfour">FOUR</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the CSS...

```
ul.nav li ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position:absolute;
    display: block;
    left:-9999px;
}

ul.nav li ul li{
    float:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}

ul.nav li ul li a{
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}

ul.nav li:hover ul{
    left:0; 
    top: 0;
}
```

Anyway, thanks for checking it out, and for any help you might be able to give.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the JavaScript function of onclick. You can use this as reference: [display:none; displays 'none' in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598110/displaynone-displays-none-in-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Is jquery an option for you? You tagged and mentioned it but you don't seem to be using it. I think the

```
click()
```

and

```
hover()
```

functions would come in handy for something like this. I put together a quick fiddle here with an example of how it could work:

http://jsfiddle.net/4UVfk/